# Is manual flea removal by bath and brush ok for 1 day old kittens?

Tags: cats, fleas

[This treatment video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tXhsXZ9i3to) by a specialist claims manual removal, including washing, is suggested for "newborn" kittens. "Newborn" *would* seem to suggest "one day old is included" but I just wanted to double check. Is it ok to wash and comb newborn kittens as described in the video?

Also, I've never given my cat, the mother, a bath, and since the video suggests staying away from chemicals in the vicinity of newborn kittens, I have a dilemma as to how I can get rid of the fleas on her also. Suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an acceptable flea treatment for kittens?](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/3159/what-is-an-acceptable-flea-treatment-for-kittens)

Answer (score -1):

Do not use anything on newborn kittens or their mother while the kittens are feeding off of her!!

Are the cats indoor? then you might have a problem with the fleas..

Are they outside? Then wait until they are the appropriate age and use a anti flea treatment that you got from a pharmacist.