# Liquid Dial dish soap for flea-soap(shampoo) usage

Tags: fleas, bathing

Looking for answer that is scientific in nature and not just an opinion.

When using dial (on my cat) it helps kill the fleas, sometimes better than even cheap flea-shampoos do. But like those cheap shampoos, does it or does it not kill all 4 stages in a flea's life cycle (ex. some shampoos don't kill eggs)??

Question 2 is using dial first before a store-bought, flea-shampoos does it cover say the eggs with a layer that the flea-shampoo doesn't penetrate to kill the egg??

Comment: Simple answer is, "No" x 10. I'll write an answer now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dish soap, bar soap, liquid soap, shampoo (for humans) is a no-no for cat's (or dogs). Cats skin is a significantly different [Ph](http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/skin+pH) than human skin and using [these products](https://www.vetinfo.com/subscriber/0202digest.html) can cause irritation, itching, allergies, etc. Additionally, when they groom themselves, they can ingest chemical traces that may cause other issues in the future.

For good flea control, there are many, many methods and products. Do a search here on the site and you will find many answers for [flea control.](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/107/how-can-i-get-rid-of-fleas-without-dangerous-chemicals/6518#6518)

I use [Comfortis](http://news.petmeds.com/news/flea-tick-preventatives/comfortis-for-use-in-cats/) on my cat and dog and have been extremely pleased. They both have no reaction to the treatment.

Comment: Realize that many people pass around recipes for what works best for them in almost every conceivable situation. The dial dish soap for killing fleas has gone around a bit because it does work so great to kill them.

Comment: While it may *work* it is harmful to your cat. There are some things when it comes to health and safety that you just can't "hack."

Answer (score 0):

As you are are looking for an answer that is scientific in nature.  I have to start by saying you maybe working under a false impression. There is a well researched answer at [Can dish soap really be used to kill ticks and fleas?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/17370/can-dish-soap-really-be-used-to-kill-ticks-and-fleas/17477#17477) that conflicts with the popular belief that fleas are easy to drown, soap can help wash fleas off, but it does not drown them.  There is a second answer at the same question, that indicates some dish soap that **MAY** kill fleas can be harmful to cats.

We have a couple of related questions that may also help.

- [Can I bathe my cat with shampoo?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/5805/can-i-bathe-my-cat-with-shampoo)
- [What is an acceptable flea treatment for kittens?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/3159/what-is-an-acceptable-flea-treatment-for-kittens)

Comment: You so am I reading correctly, that when I believe the fleas are "killed" (because they simply fall off at I am washing, may inactive just "appear" to be dead when I then proceed to wash them down the drain.

Comment: @Edward correct, as long as they are going down the drain the distinction does not matter.  But if the wash water is landing in the yard, where the pet will be tomorrow, it is important to know.

Comment: From @JamesJenkins linked answer: "DO NOT USE THESE PRODUCTS ON CATS, AS SOME CATS HAVE ADVERSE REACTIONS."